# What does the --network option of `kind create cluster` do?

Tags: docker, kind

```
 kind create cluster --help
Creates a local Kubernetes cluster using Docker container 'nodes'

Usage:
  kind create cluster [flags]

Flags:
      --config string       path to a kind config file
  -h, --help                help for cluster
      --image string        node docker image to use for booting the cluster
      --kubeconfig string   sets kubeconfig path instead of $KUBECONFIG or $HOME/.kube/config
      --name string         cluster context name (default "kind")
      --network string      docker image to add the nodes to
      --retain              retain nodes for debugging when cluster creation fails
      --wait duration       Wait for control plane node to be ready (default 0s)

Global Flags:
      --loglevel string   DEPRECATED: see -v instead
  -q, --quiet             silence all stderr output
  -v, --verbosity int32   info log verbosity
```

What does the --network option do? I could not find any documentation on the kind website itself and my current understanding of docker does not allow me to parse the description.

How can nodes be added to an image? What does that even mean? Does this not relate to `docker network` in any way?

Comment: I'll be honest, it looks like a typo. And probably should say "Docker Network". Would be interested in hearing what others have to say, though.

Comment: What does `kind version` give you? I don't even have that flag.

Comment: I also don't see it in the kind [`ClusterOptions` struct](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/blob/master/pkg/cluster/internal/create/create.go#L59) or the [CLI options](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/blob/master/pkg/cmd/kind/create/cluster/createcluster.go#L46) in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I does indeed just add all nodes to the specified docker network. I've probably used an old version of kind, to which I have no access anymore.